# I accidentally removed my project using cmd command rd. git /s/q

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I tried to upload my project to GitHub but accidentally deleted it. How can i restore it?

Comment: Did you push your changes before you deleted your local .git folder? If so just pull from server. If you didn't you can try to recover your files.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is no straight forward way to do that as `rd` command doesn't put the folder into the bin, it moves it straight into folder heaven. However, if you are lucky the files are not overwritten yet by your system, and you can use a file recovery programme such as "Recuva". I'd suggest you giving that a go.